# Azure DevOps. Define Variable Group via Runtime Variables

Tags: azure-devops

I was wondering if it is possible to define Variable Groups via Runtime Variables, like pictured below.

```
trigger: none

- stage: Stage1
  variables:
  - group: $(variablegroup1)
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: |
        echo $(Variable1)
        echo $(Variable2)
```

[image]
[image]

Importunately, I get the error:
`The pipeline is not valid. Stage Stage1: Variable group $(variablegroup1) could not be found. The variable group does not exist or has not been authorized to use.`

Is there a workaround for such error?

Comment: Have you also tried to use template expression syntax: `${{variables.variablegroup1}}` ?

Comment: That gives an error: 
`Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/test.yaml (Line: 32, Col: 12): Unexpected value '' /test.yaml (Line: 45, Col: 12): Unexpected value ''`

Comment: _Unexpected value ''_ This is because that variable cannot be resolved. @Walter Qian-MSFT provided an answer to use pipeline parameter together with expression syntax which seems like the best solution as of now.

Comment: @WinBoss Hi Friend,does the answer below resolved your question? Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we can not define Variable Groups via Runtime Variables.
As a workaround, we can use [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) instead. Here is the sample:

```
trigger: none
parameters:
  - name: variablegroup1
    type: string
    default: WOK1
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  variables:
  - group: ${{parameters.variablegroup1}}
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: |
        echo $(Variable1)
        echo $(Variable2)
```

We can change the value of the parameter when we run the pipeline:
[image]

You can also define this variable directly in yaml:

```
trigger: none
stages:
- stage: Stage1
  variables:
  - name: variablegroup1
    value: WOK1
  - group: ${{variables.variablegroup1}}
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: |
        echo $(Variable1)
        echo $(Variable2)
```

Please find more details in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/905525/reference-a-variable-group-dynamically-by-queue-ti.html).